# Restriction of "new" keyword in Javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have this JS code:

```
var A = {};
A.new = function(n) { return new Array(n); }
```

It works well in all browsers, but when I try to obfuscate it with [obfuscator](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/), it shows an error.

Is it a valid JS code? I looked into [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), but didn't find anything. I know, that browsers sometimes accept syntactically wrong code, but I want to write syntactically correct code.

Note, that I am not doing `var new = ...`

BTW. what about this?

```
var a = { "new" : 2 };  // ok?
a.new    = 3;           // ok?
a["new"] = 3;           // ok?
```

.

EDIT: Thank you all for your help! I wrote an email to obfuscator's authors and they fixed it! :)

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: [ECMAScript reference](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1.1)

Comment: It's considered as a good practice to begin a method name with a verb. `createNew()` will cause no trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your code is valid an the obfuscator is wrong (or old). `new` is a [reserved word](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1.1), that means it is not a valid [identifier](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6) (e.g. to be used as a variable name). Yet, it is still an `IdentifierName` which is valid in [object literals](http://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5) and in [dot-notation property access](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1).

However, this was not the case in EcmaScript 3, where [both of](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.1.5) [these](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.2.1) needed to be [`Identifier`s](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.6), and keywords like `new` were invalid. Therefore it is considered bad practise to use these names unquoted in scripts on the web, which might be executed by older browsers.

Comment: A test that further suggests that it's using ES3 rules: the obfuscator gives an error on `A.long = ...`. The token `long` was specified as a `FutureReservedWord` in ES3, but dropped in ES5. (Same for any ES3-only reserved words, like `synchronized`.)

Comment: In their error message, they have "JScriptCodeDom..." - JScript is a different language from Microsoft.

Comment: @IvanKuckir JScript is Microsoft's implementation of the ECMAscript standard, with some extra stuff bolted on like conditional compilation. All versions of JScript prior to the release of IE9 were based on ECMAScript 3, so it's not surprising that a JScript implementation would exhibit ES3 behaviors.

Answer (score 3):

Reserved words *can* be used as property identifiers:

```
A.new = 1
B = { function: 123 }
D.if = { else: 5 }
```

etc - it's all valid (not necessarily good) javascript.

These things are called "IdentifierName" in the specification, and the only difference between an "IdentifierName" and a regular Identifier is

```
Identifier :: IdentifierName but not ReservedWord
```

http://es5.github.io/#x7.6

Answer (score 0):

I see no errors. Lead by a dot its just a property name, just like ['new'], not any more a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

Since `new` is a reserved word, it can't be used as an identifier, although it can be used as an identifierName. See [this section](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1) of the ECMAScript specification. So your code is legal, and apparently the obfuscator doesn't understand this distinction.

To work around this, you can access it using array-style notation:

```
A['new'] = function(n) { return new Array(n); };
```

Comment: But in ES5, the right side of [dot-notation](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2) is a IdentifierName, not an Identifier. Reserved words only apply to Identifiers, not IdentifierNames (in fact, the set of Identifiers is defined as IdenfierName set minus ReserverdWord set). The OP's code is perfectly fine ES5 code; the obfuscator that parses the code is either out of date (using ES3 rules) or just plain wrong. If you link to the ES3 spec your answer would be more valid; at present you're suggesting ES5 has some rules that it does not have.