# CoffeeScript 'public' keyword not allowed

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In CoffeeScript the *public* keyword seems to be a reserved, why?

`public.foo` => can't compile

`foo.public` => `foo["public"]` (doesn't use regular dot syntax)

Comment: It's a reserved word in javascript. http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a [reserved word](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/blob/302aa6a457c3af9e6d906749da562aadae90b3c9/src/lexer.coffee#L754) in CoffeeScript because it is one of the [Future Reserved Words](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1.2) of JavaScript. You cannot use it as a variable name, and older engines would choke on it if it was used a property identifier (with dot syntax; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18750077/1048572)).